# Reading formatted input test cases from stdin :: OCaml

Tags: ocaml, scanf, stdout, stdin

I tried to minimise the code as glennsl suggested. It turns out, I don't know how to read inputs from multiple lines in OCaml.

For example, pretend, `stdin` contains the following pattern

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
3
6 7 8
```

I need to read this and print to `stdout`. I'm using the `"%d %d %d %d %d\n"` format specifier as if I know the number of inputs is 5 in advance, just to illustrate my problem.

Now the following code fails with the same error `Fatal error: exception End_of_file` (I have tried to reproduce the same problem with fewer lines of code) *if I uncomment the bottom part*.

```
let number_of_inputs1 = read_int () in 
let input_arr1 = Scanf.scanf "%d %d %d %d %d\n" (fun a b c d e -> [a]@[b]@[c]@[d]@[e]) in 
let rec print_test_case inputs = 
        match inputs with
        |[] ->(print_newline ();print_string "done test case"; print_newline ();)
        |hd::tl -> (print_int hd; print_string " "; print_test_case tl)
    in print_int number_of_inputs1; print_newline (); print_test_case input_arr1;

(*
let number_of_inputs2 = read_int () in
let input_arr2 = Scanf.scanf "%d %d %d\n" (fun a b c -> [a]@[b]@[c]) in 
print_int number_of_inputs2; print_newline (); print_test_case input_arr2;
*)
```

It prints the following now,

```
5
1 2 3 4 5 
done test case
```

I need to print something like

```
5
1 2 3 4 5 
done test case
3
6 7 8
done test case
```

How should I read such formatted input in multiple lines from `stdin` correctly ?

***The original problem I faced is what follows.***

I have a problem where the number of test cases `t` is specified in the first line of the input. The `t` test cases follow. Each test case is comprised of two lines

line#1: number of inputs `n`, for this particular test case

line#2: the `n` input numbers separated by space

I need to do some computation for each test case. Let's assume I just need to print them back to the console with a message "done test case" after each test case output.

For example if the input was the following,

```
5
3
1 2 3
3
2 1 3
6
3 2 1 5 4 6
4
1 3 4 2
5
3 4 5 1 2
```

Observe that there are `5` test cases in this problem. The first test case for example, has `3` inputs `1 2 3`, and the third one has `6`, `3 2 1 5 4 6`.

I need to print

```
1 2 3
done test case
2 1 3
done test case
3 2 1 5 4 6
done test case
1 3 4 2
done test case
3 4 5 1 2
done test case
```

So far, I have tried the following,

```
let test_cases = read_int () in (*read the number of test cases*)
let rec print_all_test_cases tc = (*define a function that will call the individual test cases*)
    if (tc > 0) (*check if there are more test cases left*)
    then 
    let num_of_inputs = read_int() in (*read the number of inputs*)
    let rec read_inputs_for_test_case n arr = (*function to recursively read all inputs for the test case*)
        if (n == 0) 
        then arr (*if everthing is read return the accumulated array*)
        else 
        let i = Scanf.scanf "%d " (fun i -> i) in (*else read the input*)
        read_inputs_for_test_case (n-1) (arr @ [i]) (*recurse for the remaining inputs, accumulating current input to the argument*)
    in
    let rec print_test_case inputs = (*print inputs for the test case*)
        match inputs with
        |[] ->(print_newline ();print_string "done test case"; print_newline ();)
        |hd::tl -> (print_int hd; print_string " "; print_test_case tl)
    in 
    print_test_case (read_inputs_for_test_case num_of_inputs []); (*call to read and print inputs*)
    print_all_test_cases (tc-1) (*recursively do the remaining test cases*)
    else () 
in print_all_test_cases test_cases
```

It prints the following to `stdout`

```
1 2 3 
done test case
```

and fails with the following error on `stderr`

```
Fatal error: exception End_of_file
```

How do read everything correctly and print as required ?

Comment: Please make a [mcve] and read [ask]. Don't just dump all your code with a description of the task and the error. Show some effort and reduce the problem to something that might be useful to others, not just to yourself.

Comment: @glennsl Thanks for your comment. I have written a shorter version where I still face the issue. I will remove the original code, if I can get this working with the solution to the shorter version.

Answer (score 1):

There is no error in your simplified code extract, uncommenting the second part should work if the stdin had the right data.

You should probably test your code with a fixed string data first:

```
let text = "5
1 2 3 4 5
3
6 7 8
"

let source = Scanf.Scanning.from_string text
let number_of_inputs1 = Scanf.bscanf source "%d\n" (fun n -> n)
let input_arr1 =
  Scanf.bscanf source  "%d %d %d %d %d\n" (fun a b c d e -> [a;b;c;d;e])
```